# Taking attributes and using the as styles with jquery .each()

Tags: javascript, jquery, each

i guess this is a pretty simple question.

I want to give my li-tags a width that matches the image thats is inside it. So far i am getting my image-attributes right for each one.

```
$("#slider1 li img").each(function(){
 var imageWidth = $(this).width();
 var imageHeight = $(this).height();    
 $(this).attr('width', imageWidth);
 $(this).attr('height', imageHeight);
});
```

But i can't seem to figure out how i transfer the imageWidth to my li-tag. I tried with:

```
$("#slider1 li").css("width", imageWidth);
```

But that just renders the same width for all the li's.

Thanks for helping out :)

EDIT: My markup:

```
<ul id="slider1"> 
<li><img src="tester.jpg"/></li> 
<li><img src="tester2.jpg"/></li> 
<li><img src="tester3.jpg"/></li> 
<li><img src="tester4.jpg"/></li> 
<li><img src="tester.jpg"/></li> 
<li><img src="tester2.jpg"/></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do:

```
 $(this).closest('li').css("width", imageWidth);
```

like this

```
$("#slider1 li img").each(function(){
 var imageWidth = $(this).width();
 var imageHeight = $(this).height();    
 $(this).attr('width', imageWidth);
 $(this).attr('height', imageHeight);
 $(this).closest('li').css("width", imageWidth);
});
```

Comment: This is the shizzle ! Thank you! testing :)

Comment: Humm wierd thing. The  $(this).closest('li').css("width", imageWidth); is setting the same width for all the li's - again.

Comment: show us your markup. this code assumes you have an img inside a 'li' or maybe create a fiddle

Comment: I made this fiddle: if you look at the result with firebug you can see that the result is correct http://jsfiddle.net/kV9Lr/ (first li: width 200px, second li 300px, fourth li 400px)

Comment: It does not set the style="width:xx" for the li's. And my image(s) has not got a width-attr before i run my function.

Comment: Ok, i just set the width manually to have different widths. I updated it http://jsfiddle.net/kV9Lr/3/ now i get (in firebug) li style="width: 180px;" an all lis (since they all the images have the same width)

Comment: Yeah i can see that :) Answer accepted. But i still doesn't work on my site. But you answered the question :)

Answer (score 6):

You can directly call just the parent `li` that contains the `img` element like this:

```
$(this).parent('li').css('width',imageWidth);
```

Note: this only works if the `img` is only one level deep under the `li`. Otherwise, use `.closest('li')` instead. `parent` will only traverse one level up, where as `closest` will keep traversing the DOM tree until it finds the element specified.

Comment: You are correct. After reading the documentation, `closest()` has several benefits over `parent()` or `parents()`

Comment: This is also setting the same width for all the li's. Hmm it seem like it is taking all the li-parents :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#slider1 li img").each(function(){
    var imageWidth = $(this).width();
    var imageHeight = $(this).height();    
    $(this).parent().attr('width', imageWidth);
    $(this).parent().attr('height', imageHeight);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

That's because the selector you're using for setting your `'#slider1 li'` width is setting them all at the same time (to whatever the last imageWidth was). You need to only set the `.parent()` width.